# Use Cloud Firestore on Flutter. But I got exception by widget Library

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I read a data from the Cloud Firestore.
I could get the data, but I caught the below exception.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot>#4f115):
The getter 'docs' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: docs

I tried some idea on stackoverflow but I couldn't resolve.

Here is my code.

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AdminHome extends StatefulWidget {
  final String email;

  AdminHome({@required this.email});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _AdminHomeState(this.email);
  }
}

class _AdminHomeState extends State<AdminHome> {
  final fireStoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String email;

  _AdminHomeState(this.email);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("This email is $email");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Admin Home Window"),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: fireStoreInstance.collection(email).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              if (snapshot.data != null && !snapshot.hasError) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(document.data()["gameName"]),
                    onTap: () {
                      print("tapped");
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/adminGameDetail');
                    },
                  ),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data == null && !snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('No data'));
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Woooops'),
                );
              }
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help it.

Comment: Check issue here and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64457942/12789200

Comment: You should check if `snapshot.hasData` before accessing its data.

Comment: Follow the examples and details on the [StreamBuilder documentation page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snapshot.data is not yet loaded while you are trying to access it. Try this:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: fireStoreInstance.collection(email).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      
      if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Still Loading"); // return whatever widget you want to show while the data is being loaded.
      if(snapshot.hasError) return Text("Error"); // Return whatever widget you want to show when an error occurs.

      return ListView(
        children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          if (snapshot.data != null && !snapshot.hasError) {
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(document.data()["gameName"]),
                ...
                ...
                ... Rest of the code
```